# Pass function pointer to run method for multithreading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, function-pointers

I have the following code below, and I want to make two threads that do the same thing except one thread calls the tick method and one calls the render method rather than have it be on the same thread. `tick` and `render` are abstract methods defined in the `State` class which each subclass must provide implementation to. They both take no parameters and return void.

```
public class Looper implements Runnable {

    private final int SECOND = 1000000000;

    private final ResourceBundle res = ResourceBundle.getBundle("game_properties");
    private final int FPS = Integer.parseInt(res.getString("FPS"));
    private final State menu;

    public Looper(State menu) {
        this.menu = menu;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        long quanta = SECOND/FPS;
        long delta = 0;
        long last = System.nanoTime();

        while (true) {
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += now - last;
            last = now;
            if (delta > quanta) {
                delta = 0;
                try {
                    State.getState().tick(); //This method in one Looper thread
                    State.getState().render(); //This method in another Looper thread
                } catch(RuntimeException e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception in Looper, Switched to Menu State");
                    State.setState(menu);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My launcher looks like this:

```
public class Launcher {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        State menu = new MenuState();
        State.setState(menu);
        Thread loopThread = new Thread(new Looper(menu));

        State.getState().init();
        loopThread.start();

    }
    
}
```

I would like this to make two loopThreads, and have each one responsible for just that one method. C++ has function pointers but Java does not, but im wondering if there is some sort of interface magic I can do to not have to duplicate my class.

I have tried making a functional interface of void parameters and return type but I did not know what to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have concerns about your code, but here's a bit of syntatic sugar that I think handles your immediate problem.  Note that in Java a "pointer" is often just a SAM -- a class with a Single Abstract Method.  In this case I just used Runnable for the SAM.

```
public class RunnableLooper implements Runnable {
   
   private State someState;
   private Runnable runMe;

   public RunnableLooper( State someState, Runnable runMe ) {
      this.someState = someState;
      this.runMe = runMe;
   }
   
   @Override
   public void run() {
      // stuff
      runMe.run();
      // etc.
   }
   
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      State menu = new MenuState();
      State.setState(menu);
      State.getState().init();

      RunnableLooper runLoopA = new RunnableLooper( menu, menu::tick );
      RunnableLooper runLoopB = new RunnableLooper( menu, menu::render );
      
      Thread t1 = new Thread( runLoopA );
      t1.start();
      Thread t2 = new Thread( runLoopB );
      t2.start();
   }
}

class State {
   public void tick(){}
   public void render(){}
}
```

If you have an older version of Java that doesn't support method references (`state::render`), then you'll have to manually make a pair of anonymous classes that do the same thing.

```
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      State state = new State();
      Runnable tick = new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            state.tick();
         }
      };
      Runnable render = new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            state.render();
         }
      };
      RunnableLooper runLoopA = new RunnableLooper( state, tick );
      RunnableLooper runLoopB = new RunnableLooper( state, render );
```